# Rails - updating a partial from a nested model on ajax file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, carrierwave

I have a rails app with a model, `products` that has a nested model, `productdocuments`. I'm using Carrierwave to upload PDFs, Word Docs, etc .. as the documents.

In my `edit.html.erb` I have my form field rendering in a partial;

```
<%= f.file_field :resource, name: "product[productdocuments_attributes][][resource]", multiple: true, :placeholder => "Resource", id: "product_productdocuments_attributes" %>
```

And an array of the uploaded docs in a partial:

```
<%= render @product.productdocuments %>
```

The issue I'm seeing is that when I upload a file, rails is triggering a render of update.js.erb on the `Product` NOT the create.js.erb from `productdocument` This makes it harder to append the partial with the new `productdocument`.

Any idea how to to trigger create.js.erb from Productdocuments?

Comment: Post your controller code

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the `edit.html.erb` there's something like:

```
<%= form_for @product, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :resource, name: "product[productdocuments_attributes][][resource]", multiple: true, :placeholder => "Resource", id: "product_productdocuments_attributes" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

which on `submit` sends request to the `ProductsController`, not to `ProductDocumentsController` as you expect. Since `@product` is a persisted record, the request goes to `update` method.

In this case, an additional form for product documents is going solve the problem:

```
<%= form_for @product.productdocuments.build, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :resource, , multiple: true, :placeholder => "Resource" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`@product.productdocuments.build` builds a new object, therefore request is going to `create` method.

Hope it helps.